# Razor editor in Visual Studio 2022 Preview (Mac)

Tags: razor, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-2022

My Razor code won't automatically format on VS 2022.

Where do I find this setting they talk about here on Windows:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improvements-to-the-new-razor-editor-in-visual-studio/

[image]

I'm hoping not to learn it's not supported on the Mac.

Comment: Can you clarify - is this VS2022, or VS for Mac 2022 that you're having issues with?

Comment: It's VS 2022 for the mac